# fullpage.js dynamically add slides using *ngFor

Tags: angular, fullpage.js

I'm trying to dynamically create new horizontal slides using *ngFor in angular.

Referring to [this issue](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/angular-fullpage/issues/27), I've downloaded and installed the latest version of fullpage from GitHub. However, my slides don't populate. Is what I'm trying to do possible?

My template is like so:

```html
<div fullpage id="fullpage" [options]="config" (ref)="getRef($event)">
    <div class="section" id="introCard-id" data-anchor="top">
        <h1>my name</h1>
        <h2>something</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="aboutCard" class="section">
        <!-- <h1>About Me</h1> -->
        <div class="infoText">
            <p>stuff
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section" data-anchor="experience" style="background-color:#254A79;">
        <div class="slide">
            <h2>Experience</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="slide" *ngFor="let experience of experiences | async">
            {{experience.title}}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section" data-anchor="skills" style="background-color: blueviolet;">
        Skills
    </div>
    <div class="section" data-anchor="portfolio" style="background-color:orangered;">
        Portfolio
    </div>
    <div class="section" data-anchor="publications" style="background-color: black;">
        Publications
    </div>
</div>
```

And the code-behind is:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-homepage',
  templateUrl: './homepage.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./homepage.component.scss'],
})
export class HomepageComponent implements OnInit {
  config: any;
  fullpage_api: any;
  navigation: true;
  parallax: true;
  projects: any;
  experiences: any;

  constructor(
    private projectsService: ProjectsService, 
    private experiencesService: ExperiencesService
    ) {
      this.projects = this.projectsService.fetchProjectsList();
      this.experiences = this.experiencesService.fetchExperiencesList();

      this.config = {
      licenseKey: LICENSE_KEY,
      anchors: [
        'top',
        'introduction',
        'experience',
        'skills',
        'portfolio',
        'publications'
      ],

      menu: '#menu',

      afterResize: (width, height) => {
        // $('#menu').
      },

      afterLoad: (origin, destination, direction) => {

      }
    };
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  getRef(fullPageRef) {
    this.fullpage_api = fullPageRef;
  }
}
```

I've ensured that the backend contains dummy data for *ngFor to work with, and that my fetching functions work as expected.

Comment: It looks like you have a typo in your code.  The `!` in  `*ngFor!="`.

Comment: Sorry, yes, it fails without that though.

Comment: I have a sandbox example which in which the slides populate.  The only problem is that the sample slides (Title 1, Title 2, etc) is stacked.  I'm not certain if that's a CSS limited to my example, or the same problem you're facing.  Take a look and let me know.  https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-stallman-84x09

Comment: are you sure your services is returning anything, I modified the stackblitz to take observables and it renders ok, see here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hjqlun

Comment: The issue you mention was fixed and merged into the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

I was lacking a subscription. Thanks to @Paul for the answer.

Adding:

```js
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.experiences.subscribe(_ => {
      console.log('rebuild');
      this.fullpage_api.build();
    });
  }
```

Fixed the issue. Only works on the latest version of fullpage.js. Otherwise the slides stack on top of one another. If anyone has any suggestions or better ways to do this, please let me know.